# I can't log in to the web application, internal server error

Tags: python, web-applications, mariadb, mysql-connector

I try to create an application, but every time I try to connect using login I get the same message from the server, but I can't find the error in the application. My suspicion is that the data entered in the registration form is not retained, as I do not receive the message of Successfully Registered.

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
> your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
> the application.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
import re
import mysql.connector

mydb= mysql.connector.connect(
     host= "localhost",
     user="root",
     password="root",
database="app"
)
 
app = Flask(__name__)
  
  
app.secret_key = '1234'
  
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'app'
  
mycursor=mydb.cursor()

  @app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        
        mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s AND password = % s', (usern>
        account = cursor.fetchall()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account['id']
            session['username'] = account['username']
            msg = 'Logged in successfully !'
            return render_template('index.html', msg = msg)
        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect username / password !'
    return render_template('login.html', msg = msg)
  
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
   session.pop('loggedin', None)
   session.pop('id', None)
   session.pop('username', None)
return redirect(url_for('login'))
  
@app.route('/register', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and>
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        city = request.form['city']
        country = request.form['country']    
        
        mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s', (username, ))
        account = cursor.fetchall()
        if account:
            msg = 'Account already exists !'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'Invalid email address !'
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
            msg = 'name must contain only characters and numbers !'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s,>
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered !'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
 return render_template('register.html', msg = msg)
  
  
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    if 'loggedin' in session: 
        return render_template("index.html")
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
  
  
@app.route("/display")
def display():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = % s', (session['id'], ))
        account = cursor.fetchall()    
        return render_template("display.html", account = account)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
  
@app.route("/update", methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    msg = ''
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form>
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']
            email = request.form['email']
city = request.form['city']
            country = request.form['country']    
            mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s', (username, ))
            account = cursor.fetchall()
            if account:
                msg = 'Account already exists !'
            elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
                msg = 'Invalid email address !'
            elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
                msg = 'name must contain only characters and numbers !'
            else:
                cursor.execute('UPDATE accounts SET  username =% s, password =% s, email =% s, or>
                mysql.connection.commit()
                msg = 'You have successfully updated !'
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
        return render_template("update.html", msg = msg)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host ="localhost", port = int("5000"))
```

Or maybe it's a problem with how I connect to the database.
And that appears in the terminal

> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2022 11:09:49] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2022 11:09:49] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - [2022-01-04 11:09:50,376] ERROR in app: Exception on /login
> [POST] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in
> wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in
> full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in
> full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in
> dispatch_request
> return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
> File "/home/alexandra/app/app.py", line 34, in login
> mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s AND password = % s', (username, password, ))   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py",
> line 542, in execute
> raise errors.
> ProgrammingError( mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used
> in the SQL statement
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2022 11:09:50] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: What do the server side logs show?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to put spaces between the % and the format specifier:

```
mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', (username, password))
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: I tried and the problem remained. File "/home/alexandra/app/app.py", line 34, in login
    mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', (username, password, )) 
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Answer (score 0):

create a folder in the name of "Templates" and add your html files in it . Then run . This worked for me

Comment: This might have worked for you, but it would not have fixed the original poster's problem, which was that their SQL statement was wrong.  When answering, please address the specific issues in the question and not just the question title.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).